# How to convert lat longs into degree format for Google Earth?

Tags: xslt, geocoding, google-earth-plugin

I have lat/long coordinates for a list of ports.  The coordinates are in a 2856N 05211E format (totally made those numbers up, btw).  I'm trying to figure out how I can convert them to the degree format the Google Earth pluginuses in order to plot them on a map.  Is there a parameter in the API that I could use to convert this?  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: What format is your input? (It might help with to show a real data point)

Comment: I don't have a real data input right now.  Basically, it's a four or six digit N/S coord and a five or seven E/W coord.  The difference in the 4/6 or 5/7 seems to be if a data point is including seconds or not.

Comment: Are you sure it's DMS, and not just decimal with an implied decimal point? Also, what programming language are you parsing these with?

Comment: I wasn't sure it was DMS.  I figured if it was just a 4 or 6 digit string, the seconds were implied.  Trying to do this in XSLT.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you can parse the values yourself.  If not, then provide the language you wish to use.

The conversion is simple, Degrees/Min/Sec(DMS) to Decimal Degrees is

```
result = D + M/60 + S/3600;
```

If S or W,

```
result *= -1;
```

As always, do your own error checking.

-90 <= lat <= 90

-180 <= lon <= 180

Comment: Thanks, this goes a long way.  I'm trying to do this in XSLT.  My original question was whether there was something in the API that could convert this to Degrees, Minutes and seconds so I was just trying to get an idea how to do that part.  Now that I've got a basic idea how to do the DMS, I need to figure out how to break the numbers from a string of 4/6 or 5/7 into DMS using XSLT.  There's probably some examples out there.  Again, appreciate the help!