# How do I insert a decimal point into a string in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm looking for some help formatting geo-coordinates in XSLT.  Right now I've got a list of coordinates that look like the following:

2526N 05111W

or

252611N 0511111W

I need to figure out how to insert the decimal point so this can be treated as KML for a Google Earth Plugin (so something like 25.26 and -051.1111).

I'm also not sure how to treat the N/S or E/W condition in coordinates so that when coords are from S or W, they are assigned a -1.  I'm guessing I'll need to use a 'contains' function but I'm not sure how that gets formatted.  Any ideas? Thanks for the help.

Comment: How do you know it's not `-05.111`?

Comment: Please say whether you need an XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 solution, as otherwise anyone who answers has a 50% risk they are wasting their time.

Comment: **Are you sure about this?** I get the impression from [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22636170/how-to-convert-lat-longs-into-degree-format-for-google-earth) that the input is in either DDMM or DDMMSS format. Converting such input to decimal degrees is **NOT** a matter of inserting a decimal point. Also how come your input has different amount of digits for each coordinate? That's highly unlikely. I suspect you "totally made those numbers up" as you said in the other thread. And finally: what's wrong with the answer you received (and accepted) in the other thread?

Comment: So if it IS already in DDMM or DDMMSS format, why is it NOT just a matter of inserting the decimal point?  At that point, you don't need to do any other calculations like MM/60 or SS/2600, do you?  I would assume (dangerous, I know), that you just need to figure out where to position the decimal and when you need the - versus + signs.  Am I wrong on this?  Totally possible!  And while I accepted the answer, it's not in XSLT format and has no answer for how to enter the decimal point using XSLT.  Is my thinking about the decimal point off?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'd prefer an XSLT 1.0 solution.  My application uses a limited amount of EXSLT functions.

Comment: Yes, I am afraid you *are* totally wrong about this. A "252611" coordinate in DDMMSS format is ±25.43638888888889 after conversion to decimal degrees. Now please edit your question and show as the **XML** input (and a realistic one, at that).

Comment: One more thing: if your other coordinate is really 5 or 7 digits long, then I don't know what format this is in. Perhaps you should point us to the source of the data.

Comment: Ok, not in DDMM or DDMMSS format.  That makes more sense now.  Bad assumption on my part.  Thanks for the correction.